# Hamburg and surroundings, cost of year-long transportation ticket?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, germany, hamburg

I want to know how much a public transportation ticket valid one year costs for Hamburg (Germany) and surrounding towns.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the information on the [website of the regional transport association HVV](http://www.hvv.de/fahrkarten/abonnement/abopreise/).

A ticket for the *Großbereich* (the blue area in the map below) cost 1020 € for a year, to travel around in the whole HVV area you need to pay 2040 € a year.

[image: HVV map]
[Download map as PDF](http://www.hvv.de/pdf/fahrplaene/tarifplaene/Tarifplan_USAR.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Old question but it specifically mentions other cities and not the regional transport so if that is too close range, there also is the Bahncard 100 which allows free use of virtually all long-distance trains throughout all of germany including the so called Regionalbahn (the R's on above plan or the black lines on this: http://www.hvv.de/pdf/produktplaene/hvv_produktplan_schnellbahnplan_usar.pdf).
The Bahncard 100 currently is currently 4090€ per year but again, works in all of germany.

If you are looking for a cheaper option, there are CC-cards for Hamburg that work all day **except** 6-9am and 4-6pm on workdays. In that case, *Großraum* is 48.50€ and the whole HVV area is 80,40€ per month.